# Ways to extract double in a specific string format in C#?

Tags: c#, string

We have string inputs of the format `hello_EP_-12.5_201414`, `welcome_EP_22.5_20345` etc

We have to extract the double value `-12.5`, `22.5` from the above strings. The format `*_EP_double_*` is fixed.

One way to extract is to split strings with '_' and take the string next to 'EP' and convert it. The other way is to use regex, where we extract the decimal value part. Is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: Define "better". What is your current code and why wouldn't it suffice?

Comment: An alternative way (don't know is it better): find out `"_EP_"` then find out `"_"` after it; take a `Substring` and `Parse` to double

Comment: `The other way is to use regex, where we extract the decimal value part. Is there any other better way to do it?` PLease remove the **regex** tag..

Comment: Whats wrong with the two solutions you have already?

Comment: Current code has the splitting of strings with '_'. Better way which I meant is in terms of maintainability, reliability and efficient

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
 string input = "hello_EP_-12.5_201414";
 int start = input.IndexOf("_EP_") + "_EP_".Length;
 int length = input.IndexOf('_', start + 1) - start;
 double d;            
 double.TryParse(input.Substring(start, length), out d);
```

Comment: That is way too tailored to the exact string given as an example by the OP. You should try to make it valid for strings not following that exact pattern. OP states that the only fixed part is *_EP_double_* so you can't really rely on what comes after as you are doing with `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: You are missing the point. I'm not talking about content, I'm talking about pattern. Does it work for "_EP_99.999_toto_oops more stuff after"? Making it generally valid no matter what the string contains is easy as long as the pattern *_EL_double_* is met.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer this regex for extracting the Double number from string

```
(-)?\d+\.\d+
```

it does not have any constraint like `*_EP_double_*`

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/16

But in your case, you want to extract the double that followed by `_EP_`, and in this test case `12.4345_hello_ES_34.5_4444` you want the 34.5, then you have to use

```
(?<=_EP_)(-)?\d+\.\d+
```

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/17

Comment: This works as long as there is no other potential double before *_ES_*. It only returns the first match. To be fair though, based on the OP's question, this doesn't seem to be a valid scenario.

Comment: can you give an example testcases for your scenario that this code be wrong? @InBetween

Comment: Consider these two strings: "12.4345_hello_ES_34.5_4444" and "_hello_ES_12.45_3333" How do you know in the general case what *match* is the one you are looking for? 1rst? 2nd? 3rd?

Comment: Yeah, in him/her case, you are right, thank for correcting

Answer (score 0):

Not that its any better, but I fail to see whats wrong with something similar to:

```
 var parts = s.Split(new[] {"_EP_"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
 string dString = parts[1].Substring(0, parts[1].IndexOf('_'));
 double d = double.Parse(dString);
```